# Boxplot: Moving x axis tick labels base R

Tags: r, boxplot

I'm trying to use base R to make a boxplot. Is there a way to move the x axis tick labels? I've only seen the issue asked with ggplot. I just need them moved down below the graph.

Example of current tick labels

[image]

The issue comes up when I use \n in the tick labels.

```
boxplot(data$Height ~ data$Status, names=c("Loser\n(n=14)","No change\n(n=486)","Winner\n(n=18)"),  ylab="Maximum height (cm)", outline=F,
col="grey", cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, cex.main=1.5, main="", xlab="")
```

Comment: mgp might be what you are looking for http://rfunction.com/archives/1302

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have not provided all of the relevant code nor did you provide any data to reproduce your problem. Here is an example using the `iris` data set which is included in base R that may help you to fix the problem:

```
data(iris)
oldp <- par(mgp=c(3, 1.5, 0))
boxplot(Sepal.Length~Species, iris, names=c("setosa\n(n=50)", "versicolor\n(n=50)", "virginica\n(n=50)"))
par <- oldp
```

Without setting `mgp=` before plotting, the labels would overwrite the axis tickmarks. The `mgp=` argument takes a numeric vector of three values. The first is the number of lines below the plot region for the axis label, the second is the number of lines below the plot region for the tick mark labels and the third is the number of lines below the plot region for the tick marks. The default values are c(3, 1, 0) so by changing 1 to 1.5 we are pushing the tick mark labels down by one-half a line (the values are for the bottom of the label, not the top).

In your example, you have suppressed the `xlab=` label so it appears that you set the `mar=` argument too small to allow the tick labels to be printed below the tick marks or you cropped the figure above the bottom of the plot window. [image]